# Creating a new file each time

Tags: python, time, text-files

I want to have a new file created each time a button is pressed.
To make things easier I choose to use Time to make unique file names.
But for some reason this only creates the file once, and writes to it the next time:

```
import os

timestr = time.strftime("%H-%M-%S")
dpath = os.path.join(os.path.expanduser("~"), "Documents")
if not os.path.exists(dpath):
    os.makedirs(dpath)
fpath = os.path.join(dpath, timestr + ".bat")
open(fpath, "w+").write("""netsh interface ipv4 set address name="Ethernet" static """ +
                       str(sf1) + " " + str(sf2) + " " + str(sf3))
```

Comment: Shouldn't you close the file with the close() method after finish writing?

Comment: I have tried to add fpath.close() to the end but it gives cannot find reference error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please do the following to solve your problem. Follow comments and feel free to ask questions.

```
from datetime import datetime
import time


def read_to_file_once(list_of_strings):
    filename = "myfile" + datetime.today().strftime("%Y_%m_%d_%H_%M_%S")  # get date and time now
    with open(filename, mode="a") as f:  # append mode "a" create file if it even doe not exist
        for line in list_of_strings:
            f.write(str(line)+"\n")


if __name__ == "__main__":
    read_to_file_once([111, 1112, 3434])
    time.sleep(2)
    read_to_file_once([888, "ABC", 3434])
```

Comment: @Martin Wærøe hello did it help?